# How to adjust the bubble margin of the JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image]

Here, I'm using tailed and tailless bubble image for the incoming and outgoing messages. The (code for the) cell for the outgoing and incoming are pretty much alike. But, as you can see in the image, the bubble for the tailless incoming message is slightly off to the left. How can I adjust this?

I'm still learning the library but any help quick help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this 
 in fund viewdidload
 self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero

Answer (score 0):

Hey @yoninja I think what you are looking for is adjusting the `_messageBubbleLeftRightMargin` I found it in the `JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout` line 73.

Technically the bubbles are lining up edge to edge(of the tail) So you are going to want to make something that returns a different `_messageBubbleLeftRightMargin` based on wether or not it is tailed or not. This should help you get where you wanna go.